# Stripe.card.validateCardNumber returns true for some invalidate card numbers

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments, credit-card

So I'm using Stripe v2 and for some card numbers like `4242 4242 42` the `Stripe.valid.validateCardNumber()` doesn't catch any errors but if you send it to Stripe it tells you that the number is wrong! Is there any way to fix the validation issue within Stripe v2?